# Force use of an entity already create with NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to get to select or button one or two button the application will create an entity related to that neighborhood and thus show the following screens according to the selection. To avoid the creation of entities each time decided to use the NSUserDefaults and implementation is this:

```
- (void)carregarEntidadeLojaComId:(NSString *)identificadorLoja keyNSUserDefault:(NSString *)key {
    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:key]) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *contexto = [self managedObjectContext];

        NSArray *arrayLojas = [Utils carregarArrayPlist:identificadorLoja];
        NSArray *atributosComuns = @[@"titulo", @"subtitulo", @"telefone", @"endereco"];
        for (NSDictionary *dicionario in arrayLojas) {
            loja = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Loja" inManagedObjectContext:contexto];
            categoria = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Categoria" inManagedObjectContext:contexto];
            quadra = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Quadra" inManagedObjectContext:contexto];

            //Loop para atributos comuns
            for (NSString *atributo in atributosComuns) {
                [loja setValue:[dicionario objectForKey:atributo] forKey:atributo];
            }

            [categoria setValue:[dicionario objectForKey:@"categoria"] forKey:@"nome"];
            [loja setValue:categoria forKey:@"categoria"];

            [quadra setValue:[dicionario objectForKey:@"quadra"] forKey:@"nome"];
            [loja setValue:quadra forKey:@"quadra"];
        }
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:key];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
}
```

Turning the first time, the application identifies that there is no key and enters the if statement, therefore, create the entity. Already from the second time you use the application it will not enter the if statement, but he can not use the entity that has been created and so the screens that depend on them are not fulfilled. My question is how to force the application to use the entity that has been created the first time that the user clicked the application.

Comment: According to the code you created the entities without saving them anywhere.

Comment: @realtimez I'm trying to read from an plist, save on CoreData and import back to display on table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there really `NSUserDefaults` needed?

Why not just query entity from CoreData itself, like this:

```
- (void)carregarEntidadeLojaComId:(NSString *)identificadorLoja keyNSUserDefault:(NSString *)key {
    NSManagedObjectContext *contexto = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest new];
    request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Loja"
                                 inManagedObjectContext:contexto];

    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"identificador = %@", identificadorLoja];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [contexto executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    NSArray *lojas = nil;
    if ((error == nil) && [fetchedObjects count] > 0)
      lojas = fetchedObjects;

    if (!lojas) {
        NSArray *arrayLojas = [Utils carregarArrayPlist:identificadorLoja];
        NSArray *atributosComuns = @[@"titulo", @"subtitulo", @"telefone", @"endereco"];
        for (NSDictionary *dicionario in arrayLojas) {
            loja = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Loja" inManagedObjectContext:contexto];

            //Loop para atributos comuns
            for (NSString *atributo in atributosComuns) {
                [loja setValue:[dicionario objectForKey:atributo] forKey:atributo];
            }

            [loja setValue:[self categoriaWithNome:[dicionario objectForKey:@"categoria"]
                                        inContexto:contexto]
                    forKey:@"categoria"];

            [loja setValue:[self quadraWithNome:[dicionario objectForKey:@"quadra"]
                                     inContexto:contexto]
                    forKey:@"quadra"];


            [loja setValue:identificadorLoja
                    forKey:@"identificador"]; 

        }
    } else {
      // do what you want with loja's, previously stored in CoreData

      for (NSManagedObject *entity in lojas)
        ...
    }

}

- (NSManagedObject *) categoriaWithNome:(NSObject *)nome inContexto:(NSManagedObjectContext *)contexto {
  NSManagedObject *categoria = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Categoria" inManagedObjectContext:contexto];
  [categoria setValue:nome forKey:@"nome"];
  return categoria;
}

- (NSManagedObject *) quadraWithNome:(NSObject *)nome inContexto:(NSManagedObjectContext *)contexto {
  NSManagedObject *quadra = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Quadra" inManagedObjectContext:contexto];
  [quadra setValue:nome forKey:@"nome"];
  return quadra;
}
```

**Upd.**

Added `predicate` to request and removed `limit`, as it seems like you have multiple `loja`'s for each `identificadorLoja`.

Comment: Just asking but.. And how about performance to querying entity many times?

Comment: Premature optimization is root of all evil, didn't you know? >:-)

Comment: btw, CoreData is `really` fast. Don't bother with caching until you really struck in some kind of bottleneck